# Where can I get the actual info about how many stocks are there in markets all over the world?

Tags: equities, market-data

I need to test an algorithm for large-scale data in stocks market.
I wanna know how many stocks are there all over the world and the data source.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Per the [factsheet](https://www.msci.com/documents/10199/f7349d88-8c6f-46dc-bf0d-f2e02e1f5be5) for MSCI ACWI All Cap Index (as of May 31, 2019):

> The MSCI ACWI All Cap Index captures large, mid, small and micro cap representation across 23 Developed Markets (DM) countries and large, mid and small cap representation across 26 Emerging Markets (EM) countries. With **14,752 constituents**, the index is comprehensive, covering approximately 99% of the global equity investment opportunity set.

However, the liquid set of securities is far smaller. Per MSCI ACWI IMI Index [factsheet](https://www.msci.com/documents/10199/4211cc4b-453d-4b0a-a6a7-51d36472a703):

> The MSCI ACWI Investable Market Index (IMI) captures large, mid and small cap representation across 23 Developed Markets (DM) and 26 Emerging Markets (EM) countries. With **8,880 constituents**, the index is comprehensive, covering approximately 99% of the global equity investment opportunity set.

Answer (score 2):

You could also try using Bloomberg's screener (`EQS <GO>`).  You need to clarify your idea of a stock, are dual-listings of the same issue two stocks or one?  What about company issues whose trading is currently suspended?

Anyway, running the screener on just active stocks that are public companies, as of now, gives 354283 equity stocks.

Edit: More in the vein of what people think when they talk about the stock market: There are, as of now, 226379 active common stock listings, which translates to 59116 common stock issues.

Comment: Some of those could be ETFs and other things not normally regarded as 'stocks'.

Comment: @AlexC Hence my question what their idea of a stock is.  I updated my answer.